# How to use laravel query builder to get the count, distinct and total country

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I want to use laravel query builder to calculate based on country that participate in the competition.

```
Table country:
------------------
country_id
country_name

Table company:
-----------------
company_id
company_name
country_id(fk)

Table_participate_company:
-------------------------
company_id
competition_id

Table competition:
--------------------
competition_id
competition_name
```

Sample output:

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGFuK.png)

### My current query:

```
$total = DB::table('company')
                    ->join('participate_company', 'company.company_id', '=','participate_company.company_id')
                    ->join('country', 'company.country_id', '=','country.country_id')  
                    ->get();
```

Comment: Can a company participate multiple times in the same competition?